# Disabling v-navigation-drawer on specific routes, Vue-js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js

I am using a v-navigation-drawer on my webpage, but i want to disable it on specific routes, for example on the landing page. 
I am currently using the v-navigation-drawer in the App.vue file, as shown:

```
  <v-app>
<v-navigation-drawer  id ="nav"
  persistent
  :mini-variant="miniVariant"
  :clipped="clipped"
  v-model="drawer"
  enable-resize-watcher
  fixed
  app
  width="275"
  mobile-break-point


>
  <v-list style="width:275px">
    <v-list-tile   style="color: white"
      value="true"
      v-for="(item,i) in items"
      :key="item.path"
      @click="redirect(item.path)"
    >
      <v-list-tile-action style="color:#1872EF" >

   <v-icon v-html="item.icon"></v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>

      <v-list-tile-content id="list">
        <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>

    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
<v-toolbar
  app
  :clipped-left="clipped" 
  style="background-color:#FFFFFF"
>
  <p style="color:#DFDEE3" > Menu </p>
  <img src="./assets/agilebot.svg" height="44" width="150">
  <v-toolbar-title id="title"></v-toolbar-title>

</v-toolbar>
```

Which is the best way to disable it in specific routes ?

Comment: please provide the `router` code and the template combined with this template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `v-if` (or even v-show)

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-if="['home'].indexOf($route.name) === -1">
```

`home` being your landing page name in the router:

```
routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home, name: "home" }, // names are arbitrary of course
```

And in array inside v-if just add list of route names where you don't want the drawer shown.

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use with $route it returns current route name in **$route.name**

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-if="$route.name!='home'">
```

In Router

```
routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home, name: "home" },
```